# can not enable Unity C# debugging Hololens

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, hololens

I want to build app for a Hololens project, However I can not check the Unity C# projects in the debugging checkbox.Is there a way to activate it ?

[image]

Comment: Try to change build type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're currently targeting any device and not just hololens. Since you want to make an application for the HoloLens I'm guessing you already have the [Holotoolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity) imported.

If you haven't, then I'd recommend you do so as this is a great starting point for any Hololens application and it has a lot of useful tools which will make developing for hololens much easier.

If you do, you can select the Holotoolkit -> configure -> project settings. This will configure your project settings for the Hololens. When you've done that you should be able to use Debugging C# projects